# Adding parameter to WooCommerce category page url

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

The categories pages of my WooCommerce site have this url format:

```
https://<my site>/product-category/<category slug>
```

I would like to automatically add a parameter to the url like this:

```
https://<my site>/product-category/<category slug>/?_category=<category slug>
```

I have tried to write the below code snippet, but it takes some time to load due to the redirect and I'm wondering if there is a simplest way to directly add the parameter to the url before the page loads:

```
function redirect_categories(){
    if( function_exists( 'is_product_category' ) && is_product_category()){
        
        // Getting slug of the category
        global $wp_query;
        $current_category = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );    
        
        // Getting current page url to add the parameter
        $current_url = home_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        if(strpos($current_url, "?_category=") == false) 
        {
            $url = $current_url."?_category=".$current_category->slug;      
            wp_redirect($url);
            exit();
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_categories' );
```

Answer (score 1):

What if you will not redirect a user but will replace a category link if needed? I bet it will work much faster.

```
    function custom_category_permalink( $termlink, $term, $taxonomy ) {
    if ( $term->taxonomy === 'product_cat' && strpos( $termlink, 'something_required' ) == false ) {
        $termlink = get_site_url() . '/custom-slug';
    }

    return $termlink;
}
add_filter( 'term_link', 'custom_category_permalink', 10, 3 );
```

You may require adding a rewrite rule to apply proper content to your new URLs, here is an answer from SO: [LINK](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/144329/wp-rewrite-rules-custom-post-type-taxonomy)

If this is not working for you, please add some details to your scenario.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Such code works well when I click on the link to view a category from the WP backend, but it doesn't work when I directly type the category permalink in the browser, or when using internal links.  Would you know how to bypass this issue?

Comment: @JulienVan I can suggest you add a rewrite rule for that. I will update my answer in a moment.